# Extrapolation of points by a function

Tags: polynomials, spline, extrapolation

I have got a positive series convergent series $w_j$, which is convergent. I can calculate a finite amount of terms $\sum_{j=0}^{j^*}w_j$ and would be interested in the estimation of the sum of the remaining terms $\sum_{j=j^*+1}^{\infty}w_j$.

I thought it would be nice doing so by using the property $s_k+\int_{k}^\infty f(x)dx\leq s\leq s_k+\int_{k+1}^\infty f(x)dx$. 
The series is not possible to integrate or differentiate, so I would replace it by a (extrapolation) polynomial $f(j)$.

I would like to interpolate the data points with a function that satisfies the properties:

1. the function is integratable
2. converges to 0 in infinity
3. is positive and eventually $\forall j \geq j_0:\, f(j)\geq w_j$

I tried to create a Newton interpolation polynomial, which unfortunately diverges as seen in the picture:

[Newton interpolation polynomial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWceY.jpg)

I am not really interested in the interpolated values, but in the values for $\forall j \geq j_0:\, f(j)\geq w_j$

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question isn't clear (to me). The picture suggests that you have a _sequence_ of positive numbers with limit $0$. Must your interpolation have a formula? If not, just connect the data points. That won't be integrable in every case - a counterexample would be the harmonic sequence at the integers. So please edit the question to provide more information. Where does your sequence come from? What properties does it have?

Comment: You do not seem to have a problem with interpolation, but only with extrapolation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments so far. I am editing my question to be more precise.

Comment: The question is clearer now. That said, I think it wouldn't be hard to show that such functions exist, but in order to find one that would be useful for any particular series you would have to rely on properties of the series.